# Allow clear cache options for BE_USERS TYPO3?

Tags: caching, typo3

I have created two new users in TYPO3 backend, role not like admin but i want those users to allow cache clear options for "Frontend cache" and "general cache" near "Logout" button in backend.

Comment: @jokumer rather then for every single user, add it to the usergroup, same setting in `Options -> TSconfig`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set this via UserTSConf for each user or user group:

```
options.clearCache.all = 1
options.clearCache.system = 1
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to add this typoscript to their user accounts:

```
options.clearCache.pages = 1
options.clearCache.system = 1
```

Source: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/singlehtml/#clearcache-pages

Answer (score 7):

In 9 LTS it is:

```
options.clearCache.all = 1
options.clearCache.pages = 1
```